# Create multiple instances of the model in one query

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

There is a form with several fields and a view that processes it

**views.py**

```
class VehiclesBlacklistAddView(ObjectAddView):
    model = Vehicle
    form_class = VehicleForm
.....

    def process_valid_form(self, request, form):
        form.instance.save()
```

It's OK, it works. But now I want to be able to add several values to one of the item_id fields of the form by comma and create several instances instead of one

**views.py**

```
def process_valid_form(self, request, form):
    # print(form.instance.__dict__)
    items = [id.strip() for id in form.instance.item_id.split(',')]
    for i in items:
        form.instance(item_id=i).save()
```

But got an error

```
'Vehicle' object is not callable
```

**models.py**

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):

    item_type = models.CharField()
    item_id = models.CharField()
    desc = models.CharField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I recommend Django Formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/

I also suggest you look into `bulk_create` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

But to answer your question:

The error is for the line `form.instance(item_id=i).save()`

That is one instance already created, one `Vehicle`.
In order to create more, you should import `Vehicle` and make instances of it and save them:

```
for i in items:
    instance = Vehicle(
        item_id=i, # this is buggy and will not be unique the next submission - should be an AutoField
        item_type=form.cleaned_data.get('item_type'),
        desc=form.cleaned_data.get('desc')
    )
    instance.save()
```

Then do not save the one instance that is bound to the form, at form save.